# Why does a pinned future implement Unpin?

Tags: rust, rust-futures, rust-pin

```
fn test<T: Unpin>(t: T) {

}

fn main() {
    let a = 1;
    let b = async {
        1
    };
    test(b) // the trait `Unpin` is not implemented for `[async block]`
}
```

Future is not Unpin, so why does pinning it (pin_mut, Box::pin, etc., which wrap it with Pin<..>) make it implement Unpin?

Comment: Because `Pin` [implements](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/struct.Pin.html#impl-Unpin-for-Pin%3CP%3E) `Unpin` if the value inside `Pin` implements `Unpin`, which is the case for [`&mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Unpin.html#impl-Unpin-for-%26%27a%20mut%20T) and [`Box`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#impl-Unpin-for-Box%3CT%2C%20A%3E) and all other pointer types in the standard library

Comment: As a side note, here's a great read on why futures must be pinned: https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/04_pinning/01_chapter.html with a lot of information about `Pin` and `Unpin` in Rust

Comment: @JonasFassbender why don't you put that answer (your first comment) in the answer box below?

Comment: @cafce25 Because I feel like though I answer OPs question in theory, I provide very little original content and no real explanation other than "look at the trait implementations" and "here is a good reference on how pinning in Rust works". Does this qualify as a full answer in your opinion? Sorry I'm still new to SO and still figuring out when to post what and where

Comment: You can quote the original documentation. Comments are not the place for answers even if short.

Answer (score 3):

Because `Pin<T>` [implements](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/struct.Pin.html#impl-Unpin-for-Pin%3CP%3E) `Unpin` if the inner value `T` implements `Unpin`, which is the case for [`&mut F`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Unpin.html#impl-Unpin-for-%26%27a%20mut%20T) (from [`pin_mut!`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/macro.pin_mut.html)) and [`Box<F>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Unpin.html#impl-Unpin-for-Box%3CT%2C%20A%3E) (from [`Box::pin`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.pin)) and all other pointer types in the standard library. Pointers implement `Unpin`, because they can be moved safely, since moving the pointer does not affect the pointee. See the `std::pin` module's [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/index.html).

A great read on how pinning in Rust works and why we need to pin `Future` types can be found in the [async book](https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/04_pinning/01_chapter.html).

Comment: I would add the moving the pointer doesn't move the pointee, and this is why they're `Unpin` unconditionally.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman thanks for the tip, it makes the answer much clearer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, also have seen source code, The Type which does not implement Unpin(Future etc.) int Pin<T> can not get mut ref safely.